# Style markup using floats

Tags: css, css-float

Given this markup,

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>

#header {
  no styles at all
}

#content {
  float: left;
}

#sidebar {
  float: right;
}
```

How do I position the divs using CSS floats without changing the markup?

[image]

Comment: how does your layout has to behave on lower/bigger screen resolution? you need to center all? header and content become wider? What did you tried?

Comment: Did you try any CSS? Or do you want the answer for "free?"

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan header usually the same, content and sidebar grow in to the particular width. Now my layout have no center. I think it's not a problem apply margin auto to body after all if need.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks of course I tried. I have some question in my head and want to see how people usually do it. I want to compare to other. I have a problem that I always get header at the level of content block but I need header to be at the level of header in vertical polarity.

Comment: Can you add to the question what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need smth like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/JVJ9Q/2/

Comment: Yes, I was using the same floats. Seems `margin-top:-100px;` was my issue with sidebar as I see. Maybe you know what other methodologies can be applied to do the same that you show not using negative margin? Is that good to use negative at all?

Comment: @A-STAR check out Fabrizios friddle! use that one ;]

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PZkeh/

Respect to Pēteris answer you don't need to define a negative `margin-top` that is strictly dependant on #header `height` and works quite well on window resize.

The main css rules to make this layout are

```
#sidebar { 
    position: absolute; 
    right   : 0; 
    top     : 0;
    width   : 100px;
    min-height: 150px; 
}

body {
    position: relative; /* not necessary if you apply this style to the body */
    padding-right: 120px;
    min-width: 300px; /* this should be adjusted to contain sidebar + header width */
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's good idea too. Still have a small issue with resizing in same time. But thank you.